# 16.04 - boot stops at "A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up(time/no limit)

Tags: boot, 16.04, gdm

I have ubuntu 16.04 LTS running on my Pentium E2180 , 1GB RAM computer, with a 120GB SSD. I had recently installed gnome-shell, to try it out , and I got an option asking me to choose between gdm3 and lightdm. I chose gdm3 and rebooted. The ubuntu loading screen showed up , and I noticed it was taking longer than usual(most of the time i'm at login prompt in a few seconds). I then sweitched to a tty and it said

```
(2/2)[***   ]A start job is running for Hold for boot processes to finish up(5min30/no limit)
```

I am currently on Puppy Linux for now , but I'd like to have this fixed. What can I do? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I fixed it myself. This is what I did

- From the GRUB menu , I selected recovery mode
- At the recovery menu , I selected the 'networking' option, and then root shell.
- I then typed

  ```
  dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
  ```
- At the prompt I selected 'lightdm'
- And voila! Problem solved.

Comment: this did not work for Ubuntu 18.04 and VM version 6

Answer (score 2):

I think LightDM supports both Gnome and Unity on Ubuntu 16.04.

Open up the tty, login as root and run these commands.

```
apt-get update
```

Disable gdm service just in case

```
service gdm disable
```

Remove gdm

```
apt-get remove gdm
```

Remove other unneeded gdm dependencies

```
apt-get autoremove
```

Install lightdm

```
apt-get install lightdm
```

If it doesn't make you choose a display manager when installing, or just in case enable lightdm service.

```
apt-get enable lightdm
reboot
```

It should open up lightdm after reboot, and by default Ubuntu uses lightdm if I'm not mistaken, hope this helps.

Comment: It does but with lightdm you can't manually lock screen on gnome...

Comment: In some cases you might need to substitute gdm3 for gdm in the commands. Also `apt-get enable lightdm` produced `E: Invalid operation enable`.  Instead I used `systemctl enable lightdm`