# Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 upgrade results in failed boot ("A start job is running for Hold...")

Tags: 14.04, boot, 16.04, upgrade

A few hours ago I upgraded from 14.04 (LTS) to 16.04 (LTS), and following a restart, discovered that I couldn't reach the login screen.

I did some research and found that a `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F{1,2}` would allow me to enter a terminal. This didn't work, but what it did show me was the issue:

"A start job is running for Hold... finishes up (`time since start` / no limit)".

There are [other posts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/792129/16-04-boot-stops-at-a-start-job-is-running-for-hold-until-boot-process-finish) about this, but every single one starts with:

1. Rebooting into recovery mode - I can't do this, with both shift keys I never enter recovery mode.
2. Booting from a disc - I just burnt the latest (16.04.1) iso to a DVD and attempted to boot from it, it took me to the exact same blank screen.

Since neither work, I can't even attempt to patch the issue.

Has anyone any ideas? I'd like to follow the other posts which list solutions, but being taken to a blank screen and no terminal is making me pull my hair out!

P.S I attempted to find terminal access using `Ctrl`+`Alt`+F keys 2 through 6, but they all list the same log entry ("A start job...").

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please confirm that you cannot boot to a live session (usb or dvd)

Comment: Hi - correct. I don't own a USB stick large enough for the iso, so I haven't tried that approach, but with a DVD it's not booting.