# Sometimes Ubuntu gets stuck on logo image during boot process

Tags: 16.04, boot, dual-boot

I have a dual boot system with Ubuntu 16.04 and Win 7 but I only use Ubuntu for many years now. Suddenly, for a couple of weeks now, Ubuntu sometimes gets stuck  on logo screen during boot process when I power on my laptop. After one or two restarts (with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>) it boots normally. I don't know if that happens on windows also because I always boot on Ubuntu at first and then I try on Windows.

How can I figure out if the problem is an Ubuntu issue or a laptop issue ?

### Update 1

In order to find the boot messages of my previous reboot, I ran the following commands to create the journal folder:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/journal
sudo systemd-tmpfiles --create --prefix /var/log/journal
```

After that I set Storage=persistent in /etc/systemd/journald.conf
and then:

```
systemctl restart systemd-journald
```

Thus, I ran:

```
journalctl -b1
```

which displayed a log file of 2149 lines which on one hand is above the limitation of 30000 characters and on the other hand it contains much personal information. Can I run a more issue-oriented command like:

```
journal -b1 | grep <something>
```

in order to identify the error ?

### Update 2

Finally I figure out that my boot get stuck because of the following error:

```
A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (Xmin Xs/no limit)
```

I found solutions from the following related topics:

[Cannot boot system due to start job running for hold](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760825/cannot-boot-system-due-to-start-job-running-for-hold)

[16.04 - boot stops at "A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up(time/no limit)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/792129/16-04-boot-stops-at-a-start-job-is-running-for-hold-until-boot-process-finish/792157)

https://www.rffuste.com/2016/10/01/ubuntu-16-04-a-start-job-is-running-for-hold-until-boot-finishes-up-error/

but neither worked for me.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried [logging boot messages](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-49925.html)?

Comment: In ubuntu 16.04 doesn't exist /etc/default/bootlogd file. I tried journalctl -b0 SYSLOG_PID=1 command but it displays only the last boot process which is successful.

Comment: Finally I found the error. During the boot process it raises the following: A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (Xmin Xs/no limit). I 'll update my question.